# Is there a way to change avatar in telegram bot using python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I was trying to find some documentation, but i`ve failed. I would be grateful if you send me doc or example how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change your profile photo you should use MTPROTOAPI. One of the good libraries written in Python is called [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/index.html). You can check [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/examples/users.html) on how to update profile information.

install telethon:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade telethon
```

update profile photo:

```py
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.photos import UploadProfilePhotoRequest


# Use your own values from my.telegram.org
api_id = 12345
api_hash = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'

client = await TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

await client(UploadProfilePhotoRequest(
    await client.upload_file('/path/to/some/file')
))
```

Comment: Would this also work for a user account?

Answer (score 2):

For those who just want to change without programmatically:

1. Send the command /setuserpic to the bot responsible for creating other @BotFather bots.
2. Send an image to the dialog that will be set as the bot's avatar.

[image]

[Source](https://chat2desk.com/en/knowledge-base/messenger-configuration/how-to-set-the-bot-avatar-in-telegram)